# How to boot up in kubuntu-mobile?

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, lightdm, plasma

On Ubuntu 12.04 Unity 
I just did

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-full kubuntu-mobile plasma-mobile
```

The install finished with no problems and I see Kubuntu in lightdm as an option to boot into... but I am not seeing a kubuntu-mobile option?

How do I boot into kubuntu-mobile and get the plasma mobile interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the file responsible for setting up the mobile session in lightdm at the login screen:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-mobile-default-settings
```

This will get you all the kubuntu artwork aswell for the mobile desktop.